# Since latest update R Plots have rendered through R Graphics: Device 2 (ACTIVE), an external window

Tags: r

Since latest update (4.2) R Plots have rendered through a pop out window. Titled: R Graphics: Device 2 (ACTIVE)

How can I revert so that this is coming through in the Plot pane?

I have tried using dev.off() which I seen from other threads but this hasn't worked. I've tried updating again and that hasn't worked.

[image]

Comment: What version of RStudio are you using? What does `dev.list()` show?

Comment: I am using version 4.2.2 & dev.list() returns: windows 2

Comment: That's your R version, not your RStudio version. Those are two separate things. Are you sure your RStudio version is up to date?